# Partition advice, how can I stop running out of space on "/" partition?

Tags: apt, partitioning

I run Ubuntu 10.04 on an EEEPC with a **4GB fast SSD** set as the / partition, and a **16GB slower SSD** set as the /home partition. I keep running out of space on "/", and can no longer install the latest updates, or new apps.

How can I better manage the partitions to avoid this problem? Bear in mind that the large SSD is lower performance so I don't think I should use this for the OS. Is it possible to install apps to a different partition when using apt?

Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some ways to reduce the space taken up by packages:

- **Remove your auto removable packages**: 
  go to System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager. Click the 'Status' button in the bottom left. Click the Installed (auto removable) filter. Click on one of the packages and press Ctrl-a to select them all. Next right click on one of the packages and click 'Mark for Removal'. Then click the Apply button in the toolbar. [image: synaptic autoremove]
- **Delete your cached packages**:
  in Synaptic, click Settings->Preferences and click the 'Files' tab. Click the button that says 'Delete Cached Package Files'.[image: synaptic preferences]
- **Set it so that packages are deleted once installed**:
  in Synaptic, click Settings->Preferences and click the 'Files' tab. Click the radio button that says 'Delete downloaded packages after installation'. [image: synaptic preferences]

You could create a bash script to automate these tasks:

```
#!/bin/sh
#~/clean.sh
apt-get autoremove
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

This could be run with this command:

```
sudo ~/clean.sh
```

**Diagnosing where the space has gone**:

Go to Applications -> Accessories -> Disk Usage Analyser.

Click the 'scan filesystem' button:

[image: baoabab]

This should give you a breakdown of what space is being used and where:

[image: baoabab]

**Separating parts of the filesystem to different drives/partitions**:

It is possible to put parts of the filesystem (such as /var or /usr) onto a separate  partition on a different drive. The process would be the same as separating yout /home partition, which you have already done.

These tutorials: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome and http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountlinux should give you the necessary information for this.

Comment: I would also like to recommend installing something like `localepurge`.  `ubuntu-tweak` also has an excellent system cleaner (I'd avoid `computer-janitor`).  Of course, there are also system cleaners like `bleachbit` and `fslint`.

Comment: This definitely helped, thanks very much. I also managed to clear a lot of space using ubuntu-tweak's package manager, a good tip!

Answer (score 2):

First, follow [dv3500ea's advice on removing cruft and analysing disk usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3656/partition-advice-how-can-i-stop-running-out-of-space-on-partition/3658#3658).

If you still don't have enough space on your system partition, move part of the system to the home partition. Don't create a new partition on the 16GB drive though, use the existing partition so you don't have to worry about choosing a size.

Pick one or more large part of the system for which you don't care about the speed difference.
This must be a part of `/usr` or `/var`, as the rest might be needed during boot time before the `/home` partition becomes available. Move that part to the `/home` partition, and create a symbolic link on the system partition. For example, `/usr/share/doc` looks like a good candidate, so run the following commands:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc /home/usr-share-doc
sudo ln -s /home/usr-share-doc /usr/share/doc
```

Comment: This is just the sort of thing I was looking for. I managed to clear a lot of space using dv3500ea and aperson's advice above, so I may not have to go down this route but this will be my next move, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On my old EEE701 with 4Gb, I found that Synaptic keeps all old deb files after downloading them in /var/cache/apt/archives.  If you set this to clear out after download, you might find that 4Gb is enough on its own.

In Synaptic, go to settings/preferences, choose the Files tab and select the middle option :

[image]

Comment: Got it. I normally use the apt-get in the terminal to install and I often run apt-get clean too, I think this does the same, but now I'm definitely covered! Thanks.